# (Pandas) Add a percentage symbol to the percentage

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have a dataframe  that looks like this

```
category  numbers
a         100
b         200
c         200
```

And I want to add a column that present their percentages(with the percentage symbol). So this is what I've tried

```
df['percentage'] = str(100 * df['numbers']/df['numbers'].sum()) + '%'
```

However, this would return a list of number

```
category  numbers  percentage
a         100      0 20.00 1 40.00 2 40.00 Name: numbers, dtype: float64%
b         200      0 20.00 1 40.00 2 40.00 Name: numbers, dtype: float64%
c         200      0 20.00 1 40.00 2 40.00 Name: numbers, dtype: float64%
```

What could I do to let it become 20% 40% 40%

Comment: Don't use `str(...)` but `df['numbers'].div(df['numbers'].sum()).mul(100).astype(str).add('%')`

Comment: If ```%``` will just be used to display the percentage then it's okay otherwise changing it to ```str``` type is bad practice(Assuming further mathematical operations might be carried out using percentage values).
Conversion of numbers to string during displaying will be much better than storing a number in string format in DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already commented by mozway, the key is to use [`.astype(str)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) which turns the value of each individual cell into a string, while `str()` gives you the string representation of the series as a whole.

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"numbers": [100, 200, 200]})
>>> tmp = 100 * df.numbers / df.numbers.sum()
>>> tmp
0    20.0
1    40.0
2    40.0
Name: numbers, dtype: float64
>>> df["percentage"] = tmp.astype(str) + "%"
>>> df
   numbers percentage
0      100      20.0%
1      200      40.0%
2      200      40.0%
```